# Which kernel functions are called upon page cache accesses?

Tags: cache, benchmark

I have an application and I'd like to measure its page cache hit/miss numbers. I found [this tool called cachestat](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) by Brendan Gregg, which uses the `ftrace` tool to count the number of 4 specific functions (`mark_page_accessed()`, `mark_buffer_dirty()`, `add_to_page_cache_lru()`, and `account_page_dirtied()`) to find out the total number of page cache accesses and page cache misses. Detailed information can be found [here](https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-12-31/linux-page-cache-hit-ratio.html), but basically, total number of page cache accesses and page cache misses can be calculated as below:

> total number of accesses = number of `mark_page_accessed()` - number of `mark_buffer_dirty()`
> total number of misses = number of
> `add_to_page_cache_lru()` - number of `account_page_dirtied()`

When running on my system (tested on two systems, with kernel version 3.10 and 4.18 each), the hit rate becomes a negative number because for some reason, the number of `add_to_page_cache_lru()` is larger than the number of `mark_page_accessed()`, while the number of other two functions are practically zero (0~10 calls every 5 seconds, compared to hundreds of thousands ~ millions for the other two functions)

As Brendan explains it in this [thread](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/issues/21), different kernels may use different kernel functions to access (or insert to) the page cache. I think that if I know what other functions are invoked upon page cache accesses/misses/hits, I could potentially modify the provided script to work on my kernel. Unfortunately, I have little to no knowledge about Linux kernels' functions, and would like your help on determining which functions are invoked upon page cache accesses.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at `strace`.  It will allow you to trace all system calls made by your program.  Then you'll need to read through it and through a process of elimination, determine which system calls are the ones your kernel uses for cache access.  Maybe start here: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/11258/how-to-use-strace-to-trace-system-calls-and-signals/

Comment: @TimKennedy system calls aren’t involved here, this is about kernel-internal functions.

Comment: Doh, yup.  Sorry, totally spaced there.  I guess `ftrace` is the right tool, but possibly without the filtering done by `cachestat`.  And reading kernel documentation for changes between the 2.6 kernels and whatever kernel @WannabeArchitect is running.